# Draw/"rasterize" irregular circle onto a 2D grid

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, grid

I'm using the midpoint circle algorithm to choose cells on a 2D grid which outline a circle. However, I need to incorporate some random noise so that I get an irregular circle, and this method won't work anymore given how it works. [Another stack exchange answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/64266/31121) describes an equation (the "pink noise" example) I'd like to try but I'm not sure on the best approach to implement it.

I can replicate the equation via code, but I'll need to start choosing grid cells/coordinates differently and I'm not sure the best solution.

How can I "rasterize" an irregular circle like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty closely simulate this with Bresenham's line algorithm. Let's say we have a function called `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)` which draws a line between `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` and the noise function:

```
private double PinkNoise(double theta) 
{
    return 1 + 0.25 * (
        0.883 * Math.Sin(theta + 2 * Math.PI * 0.468) + 
        0.159 / 2 * Math.Sin(2 * theta + 2 * Math.PI * 0.9) + 
        0.828 / 3 * Math.Sin(3 * theta + 2 * Math.PI * 0.464) + 
        0.021 / 4 * Math.Sin(4 * theta + 2 * Math.PI * 0.388) + 
        0.754 / 5 * Math.Sin(5 * theta + 2 * Math.PI * 0.443)
    );
}
```

Then rasterizing this shape simply becomes iterating between 0 and 2pi, each time getting the radius for that angle and getting the to and from positions for the line function using trigonometr (`x = cos(theta), y = sin(theta)`)

Comment: To make sure I understand, are you suggesting that I used the Bresenham line algorithm to draw the line segments, chosen by iterating from 0-2pi and getting the radius for that angle, which when connected would form my circle?

Comment: @BotskoNet exactly